# Wild cards in bat files

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, wildcard

I get periodic builds from a developer that need to be run with java.  The xls file names change each time (so I can't hardcode them).  They originally just gave me a bat file:

```
pushd "%~dp0"
java -jar KDT.jar 
popd
pause
```

This brings up a file chooser where you select a file.  For obvious reasons, this won't work in batch.  So I changed it to

```
pushd "%~dp0"
java -jar KDT.jar "../test data/sprint3/fil1.xls"
java -jar KDT.jar "../test data/sprint3/fil2.xls"
...
java -jar KDT.jar "../test data/sprint4/fil1.xls"
java -jar KDT.jar "../test data/sprint4/fil2.xls"
popd
```

But as I say the file names will change (but not the directories).  In Linux/Unix I would do something like

```
for fil in ../test*/*.xls
do
    java -jar KDT.jar $fil
done
```

a bit complicated because the directory name has a space.  Anyway I tried to convert this BASH to a .bat and with some research I wrote this (this is just the test to do the echo, not actually doing the Java since java takes so long I just do echo):

```
pushd "%~dp0"

for %%i in ("../test data/sprint3/*.xls") do (
   echo %%i
)

for %%i in ("../test data/sprint3/*.xls") do (
   echo %%i
)

@echo STOP
popd
```

The problem is that this is echoing just the basename of the file (i.e., without the directory name):

```
01.1v1.06_VK_210516.xls
01v1.03_SR_190516.xls
1.02_v0.09_SR_200516.xls
...
```

When I do try it with Java it is the same problem, it cannot find the file in the current directory.  I would like to have the wild card result to the full path name like ../test data/sprint3/01.1v1.06_VK_210516.xls (from what I seem to see, though the backslash () is used to separate path names in directories, .bat files seem to (additionally) accept front slash (/)).

How can I get the full (relative) directory name in the wild card?  I guess also the full path starting from C:/ would also be acceptable.  If there is not an explicit way to do that then maybe in each for statement I could manually concatenate the file name, but I am not sure how to do that (in BASH it would be something like full= "../test data/sprint3/$base" (where baseis the basename of the file).

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `echo %%i` with `echo %%~fi`.

See `for /?` for more options (drive, path, drive and path, extension, ...)

Comment: Thanks.  That works but it won't let me click the check mark ;-)

Comment: The echo works, but when I use java -jar KDT.jar "%%~fi" it says the file is not found.  Using without quotes, just %%~fi looks at just the last part to the right of the space.  There must be something I am not doing correctly with quotes?